# encode string in utf-8 and saev in another string in encoded format

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, nsdata

one,

I am getting string like this

> "User_Name" = "\U0639\U0644\U0649 \U0639\U0628\U064a\U062f";
>   and when store in string then it show 
>   على عبيد

Now I want to convert in and opposite manner like

> على عبيد  -------->"\U0639\U0644\U0649 \U0639\U0628\U064a\U062f"

I have use this code

```
  NSData *data=[NSData dataWithBytes:[y_dict[key] UTF8String] length:strlen([y_dict[key]UTF8String])];
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",newStr);
```

But it is not working.

How can I fix that issue?

Comment: "it is not working" isn't nearly enough information. What happens? Do you get some of the characters but not all? Nothing at all? Incorrect characters?

Comment: `\Unnnn` is only used by the `description` method of `NSDictionary` to print all non-ASCII characters. That means that the dictionary value actually contains the character "ع", and not the literal string "\U0639". -  Why would you want to convert a string to that format?

Comment: `NSString` uses an unspecified internal format, one can not influence it. The place where formats become important is in creating an exporting from and to some other format, this is usually from/to `NSData` and some form if `char *` or display. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want it, but here you are:

```
NSData *utf8 = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableString *newStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:[utf8 length] * 6];
const uint8_t *bytes = [utf8 bytes];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [utf8 length]; i++) {
    [newStr appendFormat:@"\\U%04x", (unsigned)bytes[i]];
}
```

Comment: `initWithCapacity` is not needed and by all accounts does nothing. The docs say it is only a hint. Don't bother with it, a simple `[NSMutableString new]` accomplishes the same thing without the additional code.

Comment: @Zaph If the class doesn't use the hint at the moment, then that may change in the future.  The *capacity* is easy to calculate in this example and adds to the readability of the code, so I would prefer to keep it.